# Disintegration of measures: a confusion about an existence proof from a lecture note

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, metric-spaces

I'm reading a proof of **Theorem 2.25** below from this [note](https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/%7Evangaans/TA2011-gradient-mei11.pdf). First, we recall a definition and a theorem, i.e.,

---

> **Theorem 2.25 (Disintegration).** Let $\left(Z, d_Z\right)$ and $\left(X, d_X\right)$ be Polish spaces, let $\pi: Z \rightarrow X$ be a Borel map, let $\gamma \in \mathcal{P}(Z)$, and let $\mu(A):=\gamma\left(\pi^{-1}(A)\right)$ for $A \subseteq X$ Borel. Then for every $x \in X$ there exists a $\nu_x \in \mathcal{P}(Z)$ such that
>
> - (i) $\nu_x$ is concentrated on $\pi^{-1}(\{x\})$, that is, $\nu_x\left(Z \backslash \pi^{-1}(\{x\})\right)=0$ for $\mu$-almost every $x \in X$,
> - (ii) $z \mapsto \nu_{\pi(x)}(C): Z \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Borel measurable for every Borel $C \subseteq Z$, and
> - (iii) $\int_Z f(z) \mathrm{d} \gamma(z)=\int_X\left(\int_{\pi^{-1}(\{x\})} f(y) \mathrm{d} \nu_x(y)\right) \mathrm{d} \mu(x)$.
>
> **Definition 2.28.** Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, $(T, \mathcal{B})$ a measure space, $F: \Omega \rightarrow T$ a measurable map, and $\mathcal{C} \subseteq \mathcal{F}$ a sub- $\sigma$-algebra. A (regular) conditional probability distribution for $F$ given $\mathcal{C}$ is a function $P_{F \mid \mathcal{C}}: \mathcal{B} \times \Omega \rightarrow[0,1]$ such that
>
> - (a) $B \mapsto P_{F \mid \mathcal{C}}(B, \omega)$ is a probability measure on $\mathcal{B}$ for $\mathbb{P}$-almost every $\omega \in \Omega$
> - (b) For every $B \in \mathcal{B}$ the $\operatorname{map} \omega \mapsto P_{F \mid \mathcal{C}}(B, \omega)$ is $\mathcal{C}$-measurable, and $P_{F \mid \mathcal{C}}(B, \omega)=\mathbb{E}\left[1_{\{F \in B\}} | \mathcal{C}\right](\omega)$ for $\mathbb{P}$-almost every $\omega \in \Omega$.
>
> **Theorem 2.29 (Existence of regular conditional probabilities).** If $T$ is a separable complete metric space, $\mathcal{B}$ its Borel $\sigma$-algebra, $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ a probability space, $F: \Omega \rightarrow T$ a measurable map, and $\mathcal{C}$ a sub- $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathcal{F}$, then there exists a regular conditional probability distribution $P_{F \mid \mathcal{C}}$ for $F$ given $\mathcal{C}$ on $\mathcal{B} \times \Omega$. It is unique in the following sense: if $P^{\prime}$ is another regular conditional probability distribution for $F$ given $\mathcal{C}$, then for $\mathbb{P}$-a.e. $\omega \in \Omega$ we have
> $$
> P^{\prime}(B, \omega)=P_{F \mid \mathcal{C}}(B, \omega) \text { for all } B \in \mathcal{B} .
> $$

---

**My question:**

1. I got that both $P_{F \mid \mathcal{C}}(B, \cdot)$ and $\mathbb{E}\left[1_{\{F \in B\}} \mid \mathcal{C}\right]$ are constant on $\pi^{-1}(\{x\})$. If $\gamma (\pi^{-1}(\{x\})) >0$, then surely $P_{F \mid \mathcal{C}}(B, z)=\mathbb{E}\left[1_{\{F \in B\}} \mid \mathcal{C}\right](z)$ **for all** $z \in \pi^{-1}(\{x\})$. If $\gamma (\pi^{-1}(\{x\})) =0$, i.e., $\pi^{-1}(\{x\})$ is a $\gamma$-null set, then I don't know how the author obtains his conclusion. Could you elaborate on this point?
2. How do we know that $Z_1, X_1$ are indeed measurable?

---

**Proof of Theorem 2.25**

Take $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})=\left(Z, \mathcal{B}_Z, \gamma\right), \mathcal{C}=\left\{\pi^{-1}(A): A \in\right.$ $\left.\mathcal{B}_X\right\},(T, \mathcal{B})=\left(Z, \mathcal{B}_Z\right)$, and $F(z)=z$ for all $z \in Z$. Then the regular conditional probability $P_{F \mid \mathcal{C}}: \mathcal{B}_Z \times Z \rightarrow[0,1]$ exists.

For each $B \in \mathcal{B}_Z, z \mapsto P_{F \mid \mathcal{C}}(B, z)$ and $z \mapsto \mathbb{E}\left[1_{\{F \in B\}} \mid \mathcal{C}\right](z)$ are equal $\gamma$-almost everywhere on $Z$. Both are $\mathcal{C}$-measurable and therefore constant on each set of the form $\pi^{-1}(\{x\})$, where $x \in X$. (Otherwise the subset of $\pi^{-1}(\{x\})$ where it equals one of the different values would be a non-empty strict subset, but there is no Borel set $A$ in $\mathbb{R}$ for which $\pi^{-1}(A)$ is a non-empty strict subset of $\pi^{-1}(\{x\})$, which contradicts the $\mathcal{C}$-measurability.) From constant and almost everywhere equal, it also follows that $P_{F \mid \mathcal{C}}(B, z)=\mathbb{E}\left[1_{\{F \in B\}} \mid \mathcal{C}\right](z)$ **for all** $z \in \pi^{-1}(\{x\})$ (and not just for almost all $z$).

Let **$Z_1$ be the set** of all $z \in Z$ for which $B \mapsto P_{F \mid \mathcal{C}}(B, z)$ is a probability measure. Then $\gamma\left(Z_1\right)=1$. Let **$X_1$ be set** of all $x \in X$ for which there exists a $z \in \pi^{-1}(\{x\})$ with $z \in Z_1$. Then $\mu\left(X_1\right)=1$. Indeed, for every $z \in \pi^{-1}\left(X \backslash X_1\right)$ the set $\pi^{-1}\{\pi(z)\}$ doesnot contain an element of $Z_1$, so $z \in Z \backslash Z_1$, hence $\pi^{-1}\left(X \backslash X_1\right) \subseteq Z \backslash Z_1$ and therefore $\mu\left(X \backslash X_1\right)=\gamma\left(\pi^{-1}\left(X \backslash X_1\right)\right) \leq \gamma\left(Z \backslash Z_1\right)=0$.

Comment: The first part is simply wrong. Let $X=Z=[0,1]$, $\gamma$ the uniform distribution, and $\pi$ the identity. Take the natural regular conditional probability and change it at some point. It will still be a regular conditional probability. The measurability of $Z_1$ is irrelevant, any measure $1$ set with the desired property will do. $X_1$ as a projection of a Borel set is generally not Borel but universally measurable and contain a Borel set of probability $1$. Maybe use another reference; the linked note suggests two.